# SBT resolve test artifacts from Nexus. Workaround not very helpful

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm working on a project where I need to add as a dependency one of our projects lying in our nexus repositories. I need to use the test and main classes from this project.

In my build.sbt, the following fails to resolve the dependency with a message that the test configuration is not public

```
libraryDependencies += "XProj" % "XProj_2.11" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT" % "test->test;test->compile" classifier "tests"
```

This works fine

```
libraryDependencies += "XProj" % "XProj_2.11" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT" % "test" classifier "tests"
```

But I also need to use classes from the main source folder which are not resolved this way. I tried `"test;test->compile"` and although the dependency is resolved, the main classes are not fetched. Calling a method from one of XProj's test classes, fails with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` Is there any other way to add the main classes and resolve the dependency at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  val xproj = "XProj" %% "XProj" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  Seq(
    xproj % "test" classifier "tests"
    xproj % "test->compile" classifier "tests"
  )
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Nope. Same java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for one of the main classes in XProj

Comment: Are you using the same scala version across the projects?

Comment: yep 2.11.7 in both projects

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing a bit more about the configurations of your dependency, I think you probably want to change:

`libraryDependencies += "XProj" % "XProj_2.11" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT" % "test" classifier "tests"`

to something like:

`libraryDependencies += "XProj" % "XProj_2.11" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT" % "default,test" classifier "tests"`

where the `default,test` is a comma separated list of the configurations that you need to pull in.

The `->` indicators in Ivy are generally used to indicate transitive configurations for your module, i.e. if I write `test->compile` this means that the `test` configuration of my module should pull in the `compile` configuration of the dependency.

Comment: I checked the XProj dependency and there aren't any configurations defined. Adding "default,test" results to an error "cannot add dependency 'XProj...' to configuration default of module default#MyProject because this configuration doesn't exist". If I change it to "compile,test" sbt is happy but on runtime I get the "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

Comment: First question: Is this an ivy or mvn repo/dependency? If it's Ivy-based (has an associated ivy.xml), this is a bit easier vs. mvn (with a pom.xml). I'm slightly surprised you'd get different runtime vs. compile time class-paths though.

Comment: I'd be tempted to drop everything after the version number. `libraryDependencies += "XProj" % "XProj_2.11" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"` to start with. Maven doesn't have the same concept of configurations that ivy does, so the extra items may be doing more harm than good.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't compile because it can't resolve the test classes. It's getting a real pain to do something that simple with the "Simple" Build Tool...

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the names of jars/what's defined in the various pom.xml files, it's more than possible that the test classes are in a different artifact. As maven doesn't have the concept of configurations I think all it/you can do is provide a selection of artifacts (with different names) to be picked from. So it may well be you need to define two dependencies, one for the 'main' classes (in one artifact) and another for 'test' classes (in a separate artifact/jar).

Comment: Yes there is a different jar for tests in my nexus repo. I ended up copying the test jar in the unmanaged resources folder and I'm getting somewhere. SBT is resolving the dependency (only compile scope), project is compiling and the tests are starting but I'm getting different runtime errors now which I'm investigating. It looks promising now.